# Ajax request to .svc

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Folks how do i get the result from this sample code into an ng-repeat using angular?

```
<html>
<body>
<form
action="http://example.com/getResult/" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="ResultNumber" value="ID/1535LMW/2015" />
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what data will you be put in ng-repeat? simple example is <div class="" ng-repeat="post in posts"> </div>

Comment: when the request is made, how do i get the result from the response before binding to ng-repeat.

Comment: controller will do using ajax